# Is it safe to remove /bin/bash on MacOS and replace it with a symlink to /opt/homebrew/bin/bash?

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew

I've installed the latest bash 5.1.16 using homebrew, and it is located at `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`

I have also changed my default shell to `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`

However, I have lots of bash scripts that start with `#!/bin/bash`, and my `/bin/bash` is the older bash 3.2.5 that came with MacOS. I'd prefer to not have to edit all existing scripts to point to the new `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` location.

Would I cause any incompatibilities or issues if I did the following:

```bash
rm /bin/bash
ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash /bin/bash
```

Comment: This seems more relevant for [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): [Is it safe to upgrade Bash via Homebrew?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24632/253138), [Can bash be replaced entirely in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/147005/253138). My 2 cents: the major version bump from 3.x to 4.x means breaking changes, so changing /bin/bash _might_ affect built-in programs expecting /bin/bash to be Bash 3.x.

Comment: Instead of removing `/bin/bash` I'd move it out of the way (eg, `mv /bin/bash /bin/bash.orig`) and then add the symlink; this way if something in macos complains/breaks (re: Gino's comment) you can switch it back

Comment: @markp-fuso macOS might not be able to boot anymore; I wouldn't touch nor change /bin/bash

Comment: Also, in recent macOS versions, /bin (along with most other system files & directories) is pretty seriously write-protected. It's on a read-only, cryptographically sealed volume, as well as being protected by System Integrity Protection. See the Ask Different question ["Can I mount the root (system) filesystem as writable in Big Sur?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/can-i-mount-the-root-system-filesystem-as-writable-in-big-sur) and [this Eclectic Light co article](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/25/big-surs-signed-system-volume-added-security-protection/).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks, I won't mess with things then. It sounds like I wouldn't be able to change it even if I wanted to. If you feel like submitting your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as the solution.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Might I suggest you submit this as an answer, for future reference?